# Cython for pypi package structure

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am struggling to understand the Cython documentation regarding compiling.

It seems that cython prefers `distutils` than `setuptools`.

So I have a python package of similar structure to the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

e.g.

```
package
    package
    __init__.py

    subpackage1
        __init__.py
        submodule1A.py

    subpackage2
        __init__.py
        submodule2A.py
        submodule2B.py
```

and the default `setup.py` file:

```
import setuptools

from package import name, version, description

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name=name,
    version=version,
    description=description,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

I am now also working on a `cython_setup.py` file to build a compiled version.

If I wanted to `cythonize` **everything** in this package, how would I do it?

I tried importing everything into `__init__.pyx` and:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name='package', ext_modules=cythonize("package/__init__.pyx"))
```

but that doesn't actually affect the imported code...

Comment: I don't get your problem: you have no cython modules, why do you need cython in your setup file?

Comment: Also maybe a simple pyx-file would be a better point to start out? You should use specific cython documentation: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#basic-setup-py rather than distutils'

Comment: @ead While there are ways to improve Cython’s compilation by ‘cdef’ types, even with native python, compilation can provide a performance increase. So I just want to know how one would naively cythonize a package.

Comment: @ead it is precisely that documentation which I didn't understand which lead me to ask this question

Comment: @SumNeuron It's quite complicated to convert a whole package to one .so Cython file (so don't start by doing that!). You also probably don't really want to run to `__init__.py` files through Cython (they don't usually contain "real" code so it gets you no benefit). Instead you should put all of the `submodule1A.py` etc through Cython separately

Comment: @DavidW since compiled cython code can be imported just like python, if I change the extension of all my `.py` files to `.pyx` how would I naively convert my package into a cython package? I was hoping (wrongfully) that cython would trace the relative imports from the `__init__.py` and convert the functions...

Comment: @SumNeuron [There's some examples in the documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#configuring-the-c-build) showing how you use wildcards (`*`) to do multiple files. This would build multiple Cython packages but that's probably the best option

Comment: By picking up blindly all `.py` files, it would actually be much harder to use. I recommend to list the files explicitly, keep all Python files in Python and cythonize only the cython parts. The organization of the package also depends on how you intend to organize your API.